# Customizing a View with Taxonomy, color coding and icons

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, theming

I have been searching for help with this and I am stumped.

I am trying to create an attractive, styled table with categories of Web Resources and associated icons for each category.

I currently have the following:

- A Taxonomy vocabulary: technology categories (e.g. techA, techB, techC) with an icon image field
- A Web Resources content type (title, link, description, tech category = taxonomy)
- Block View of Taxonomy Terms in Table Format (built using these suggestions from Anoop Joseph (https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/10405/anoop-joseph) [How to list all taxonomy terms in a vocabulary followed by associated node titles in Views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48222/how-to-list-all-taxonomy-terms-in-a-vocabulary-followed-by-associated-node-title))

What I would like to do:

- Show the Taxonomy icons next to the technology category names in the Views table
- Style each Views generated table with a different css (e.g. border color, bg color)

But I can't find where I can create/generate specific CSS classes for each of the tables. They are all showing up in the output HTML as:

```
<table class="views-table cols-0">...</table>
```

And I don't even know where to start to display the Taxonomy icons next to the Taxonomy.

Do I need to work in Templates? If so, how do I add the appropriate icon to the table captions without hardcoding (e.g. switch / case), because that won't be flexible in the long run. I want site maintainers (not me) to be able to simply add a new category to the Taxonomy and upload an icon to go with it and have it show up in the View as a header for that category.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to have the associated icon show up with the taxonomy term, do the following:

- add field: image field from taxonomy
- add field: Global: custom text, set it to [name] [field_your_image_field]
- exclude label from display
- exclude these two fields from display
- change your table grouping from taxonomy name to Custom text ( or whatever you named it )

To style the output, you'll use two settings:

under Format: table | settings, set the row class here

to style individual fields, click on the field in the fields list, click on style settings, and customize field HTML / create a CSS class

There are lots of options here for setting field and label classes, and html elements

Good luck

Comment: Thank you, Dom Day.

This worked really well for adding the icon next to the taxonomy term.\

Comment: I was not able to find a way to style the tables themselves, but I could style each row by adding the "[name]" field token to the Row class, and then adding a separate line for each Taxonomy name to my CSS.
  
For example:  
  
    Taxonomy term = Geothermal
  
stylesheet.css:  
  
    tr.Geothermal {  
 background-color: #faeeee;  
    }

Comment: Can't figure out how to put linebreaks in comment... Help says add two spaces, but this doesn't work for me...

Comment: You can add a class to the view under the view's advanced settings area, and use it in your css selectors ... doing  something like this in the css: .myview-class table { }

Comment: Thank you again, Don, but I'm afraid that doesn't affect the code I want to style. The View outputs a series of tables, one for each Taxonomy term. The <tr>s (which I can style) are for each item with that term. But I want to style the caption for each table differently (i.e. different background color). If I add a class to the whole view, then .myview-class table {} or .myview-class table caption {} will style all captions the same. What I want to do is table.techA caption {background-color: #faeeee;}, table.techB caption {background-color: #eef2fa;}.
Any way to do that you know of?

Comment: On vacation at the moment, on borrowed laptop, so can't test, but since you're using the taxonomy term as the grouping field, you can apply a css class to your your rewritten global field with a replacement pattern based on the taxonomy term. You'll have to find a way to deal with multi-word taxonomy terms, if they exist. to add the class: Style Settings, Customize Field HTML checkbox, Create CSS class, add token for your taxonomy term from your replacement paterns, like the one you used in your global text field

Comment: oh, maybe use unique TID rather than the term itself for the replacement pattern. You'll need to add a hidden TID field though