# How can I color my taxonomy term

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

How can I add color to my taxonomy terms. Example I have terms "Working" and "Under maintenance". I want to color them green and red respectively. How can I achieve this?

Comment: when do you want to color the terms? when they're displayed or when they're added. Do you just want to change the txt color or add a background or swap it for an image?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way would to be to use [Views](https://drupal.org/project/VIEWS), as this allows a lot of flexibility and in-built functionality to customise a variety of attributes, especially using taxonomy terms. I would then follow this [Solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77851/customizing-a-view-with-taxonomy-color-coding-and-icons) which thoroughly explains how to style each row and the icons for each taxonomy term. Hope this helps.

Comment: Storing the term color as a field against the term is definitely the right way to accomplish this (so long as you can find a way to make views work with your use case).